# Why is this trivial program so large when compiled?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation

I created a file containing the following line:

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

After compiling this, I was surprised to find out that the binary for this simple program is 8328 bytes!  What is going on here, and what in the world is the binary doing in those 8328 bytes?  Surely this program can be expressed in just a few lines of assembly.

Note: I compiled this with the following line:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

My g++ version is `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1`

Comment: What platform are you compiling for? I.e. Windows, linux?

Comment: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Comment: @Matthew I'm on Linux.  64-bit Ubuntu, specifically.

Comment: @ikh and Daniel A. White - I updated the question, hopefully that answers your questions.

Comment: "Surely this program can be expressed in just a few lines of assembly." - You're forgotting cr0.o stuff...

Comment: @Griwes, nah, I'm just ignorant of cr0.o stuff.  Care to enlighten me?

Comment: @CoryKlein, it's what larsmans called "startup code".

Comment: You call 8K large? hello world is 500K on MinGW ;)

Comment: I know I'm a week late to the game, but this question reminded me of a similar Stack overflow question (albeit from a windows perspective) [what-is-the-smallest-possible-windows-pe-executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553029/what-is-the-smallest-possible-windows-pe-executable) Which points to this article: [Tiny PE](http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/) which claims 97 bytes as the smallest possible PE But wait .. this article was inspired from a previous linux based article on small files: [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.mupp

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a lot in that binary:

- a header to make the binary self-describing (try running `file` on it)
- a symbol table, which the `strip` tool will remove for you (or link with `gcc -s`)
- the names and locations of shared libraries that you never use (five of them on my box; try the `ldd` and `strings` tools)
- startup code that loads those libraries and sets up `argc` and `argv`, then calls `main`
- shutdown code that returns `main`'s return value to the operating system.

For comic effect, try linking that program statically, where your binary will include the functions that would normally be dynamically linked to DLLs. *(however, this option will simplify deployment)*

Answer (score 3):

Do a binary dump of the resulting file and check it out!

It's mostly empty space.  Data in the binary are organized into pages (commonly, 4096 or 8192 bytes in size).  That's so pages can be [memory mapped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_map) efficiently.  Typically the first page contains instructions on how to load the binary - code is at this position in the file and gets mapped to this location, same for data, etc.  The second page will probably be your code, and the third page will contain symbols and debugging information.  Each page is probably mostly empty.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting.  I did look at it with a hex editor, and there is one section that is empty, but it only consists of 46% of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother.

Try to make a less trivial program and you will discover the size is not that different, until your code will start to become various hundreds of kilobytes.

**Briefly:** There are part of the standard library that constitute the "infrastructure" between the OS modules and the C++ semantics that manage the startup and termination of the program (all that initialize and destroy the global variables, the standard input and output etc.)

**Plus:** everything that maps the C++ symbols towards the memory addresses, (if you didn't require to remove it  - try the `-O3` `-s` and eliminate the `-g` options) so that a debugger can show the proper source code references across the execution.

**Also:** because of the way the memory is laid out, a binary is normally made up by chunk of fixed size. Your program may even be shorter, but at least one code segment, one data segment initializer and one shared segment (for constant values) must be present.